# AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_xpath'

Tags: python, eclipse, robotframework

i'm using robotframework in eclipse and this error msg appears everytime i try tp run my script and nothing open except the browser

in fact i'm using python 3.9.11 , robotframework 3.2.2 , sélénium library 4.1.0

Comment: Please checkout [mre]. Add the appropriate code in your question to add more context

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.